# Prove Permutation approach of finding best paranthesization to matrix chain multiplication is $4^n$

Tags: complexity-theory, matrices

Suppose we have matrices $A_0,⋯,A_{n−1}$ (you can say $n $ matrices). Matrix $A_i$ is with dimension $d_i\times d_{i+1}$. If we would like to find all possible permutations to find the best parnthesization possible, that would take $4^n$ time complexity, any idea here please? For example, $B$ is $3x100$, C is $100 \times 5$, $D$ is $5\times 5$, the best one is $(BC)D = 1575$ ops while $B(CD) = 4000$ ops, where in this example for 3 matrices we have only 2 permutations, and we find the best one to have 1575.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks. Do you have resource pls for the same problem above?

Comment: What do you mean? The link answers your problem.

Comment: @Dmitry. I mean a problem dealing with matrices that also has catalan number complexity please?

Comment: Check “Applications …” section, an example there is that Catalan numbers compute the number of ways to parenthesize a sequence . The number of such sequences is a Catalan number, and the link also talks about $4^n$ bound.

Comment: @Dmitry. Yes. Thank you, but they don't though go deeply over proof of $4^n$. But it's clear to see that parenthesizing matrices is one example of parenthesizing sequence problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What people often forget: They have a problem, and the have a sub problem that helps solving the problem. And then they try solving the (hard) sub problem - without realising there is a much better solution.

In this case: For every (i, j), 0 <= i <= j < n, find the best way to multiply $A_i$ to $A_j$. There are j-i ways to calculate this product by multiplying two sub products, so you can solve this in $O(n^3)$.